# How to test iphone app using simulator with previos ios version in xcode 4.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

In xcode 4.1 there is only one ios version of simulator - 4.3.2. We can set up the deployment targer but I couldn't find where to change the ios version of simulator.We want to test that our app will run on devices with ios 3.1. How can we do this using iphone simulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a previous version of Xcode, containing support for the SDK you need, you can copy the SDK files over to your current Xcode installation. Have a look at this [S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851399/practical-tips-on-supporting-older-versions-of-ios).

In short, you open Xcode package in the Finder, then access the SDKs folder to copy the SDK versions you need.

Comment: that doesn't work. I installed xcode 3.2 with firmwares 2.2.1-3.1.3 and iphone simulator failed to start with error "The simulated application quit" and button to swith sdk. I could only start the iphone simulator with >= 4.0 ios version. Is there any other way to test ios app on 3.1 firmwares?

Comment: what about if you only try and use sdk 3.x? anyway, bad that that trick stopped working... sorry...

Comment: I tried, but with the same result. May be that's because I have 10.7 mac os (Lion). And there were problems with Core Data and Interface Builder files. In xcode 4.1 these files have different format and .xib file simple didn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the IOS sdk for the previous versions. You will need to install the sdk's in the following location:

**~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator**